# SFTP over Midnight Commander still asks for a password

Tags: ssh, sftp, key-authentication, mc

In linux command line, when I connect to sftp or ssh this, it connects using my public keys and doesn't ask me for a password.

```
sftp user@host
```

It also works when I do

```
ssh user@host
```

But somehow when I do an SFTP link through MC, it keeps prompting me for a password.

Does MC not use the SSH public key to connect password-less? Or is there a way to manually allow MC to use the public key authentication?

Comment: Try to log out of your workstation and log in again. Maybe it is a ssh-agent problem.

Comment: Use Shell link (`sh://joe@somehost.ssh.edu:2222/private`) instead of SFTP link.

Answer (score 4):

You have put the host in your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host your.host.name.or.ip
    User your.remote.username
    IdentityFile /path/to/your/keyfile
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked.

Answer (score 0):

This one is easier...

```
ssh-add .ssh/id_rsa
```

Found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/429386/connect-to-ec2-via-midnight-commander-with-key-pair)

Credit to El-ruso